# Using OData Filters with C# MVC 4 Web Api and Backbone

Tags: c#, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This is the first time I have experimented with the awesome Web Api and Backbone. So far everything seems like a match made in heaven. However I cant seem to return the relevant data using the OData filters. For Example I have the following as an action method:

```
    //GET /api/posts/
    public IQueryable<KiaFamilyPost> Get()
    {
        return _db.Posts
            .Include("Badge")
            .Include("Entry")
            .AsQueryable();
    }
```

Now I would like to filter the above posts, and return them in descending order. From my understanding I could do the following **"http://[MySite]/api/posts?$filter=id eq 2&$orderby=DatePost desc"**. I am trying to do the following to no avail:

```
        APP.posts_collection.fetch({data: {
            entryId: APP.entry.get('Id'),
            $order: 'Id desc'
        }});
```

Backbone makes the following call to the controller **"http://[MySite]/api/posts?entryId=1&%24order=Id+desc"**. Anyone been able to get this to work correctly?

Thanks

Tyrone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experimented with a plugin from Addy Osmani called [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator). If you are working with a Web Api like MVC 4, I believe this will be a great fit. All you do is extend your collection with a handful of parameters provided by the Paginator. Eg.

```
    perPageAttribute: '$top',

    skipAttribute: '$skip',

    orderAttribute: 'orderBy',

    customAttribute1: '$inlinecount',

    queryAttribute: '$filter',

    formatAttribute: '$format',

    customAttribute2: '$callback',`
```

Comment: Where do you write this? In the paginator_ui section or server_api section? Do you use the client pager or request pager?

Comment: You set it when you create the paginated collection. The link above has examples. Just scroll down towards the bottom. Client paginator is for paginating between models you already have in your collection. Request pager is used when you want to to make a request to the server and only receive the models based on your pagination settings. The above link should be able to discuss it more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if this code works:
(I assumed that APP.entry is your model, so to get its url I called APP.entry.url )

```
   var entryId = APP.entry.get('Id');
   var queryUrl = APP.entry.url() + '?$filter=id eq ' + entryId +'&$orderby=DatePost desc';
   APP.posts_collection.fetch({ url : queryUrl });
```

I have not tested such a code but I hope it works or at least gives you a clue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought there would be a more elegant solution since you can setup your params in fetch method. For some reason the character for $ ends up being %24. Strange, but addyosmani developed a paginator plugin for Backbone.js. He uses Neflix as an example, which their API resembles that of the MVC API. I am going to try it and get back to you.